# How to make null equal null in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a variable being passed to my stored proc and it's a filter (basically). However, that field can sometimes be null, and if it is, I want to be able to check against the rows that have that field as null.

For example,

Table A:

```
VALUE_COLUMN | FILTER_COLUMN
----------------------------
A            |  (NULL)
B            |  (NULL)           
C            |  (NULL)
D            |  (NULL)
A            |  1
E            |  (NULL)
F            |  (NULL)
B            |  1
```

The query (With inputs, val, filter):

```
SELECT  COUNT(1)
  FROM    TableA
WHERE 
  wrap_up_cd = val
  AND brn_brand_id = filter
```

Expected I/O:

```
val = A, filter = (null) = 1
val = A, filter = 1 = 1
val = C, filter = 1 = 0
```

How can I make Oracle behave this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT  COUNT(1)
  FROM    TableA
WHERE 
  wrap_up_cd = val
  AND ((brn_brand_id = filter) OR (brn_brand_id IS NULL AND filter IS NULL))
```

I'm not an Oracle expert, but I'd *expect* that to work - basically make the query match if both the filter *and* the value are NULL.

Comment: I edited the sql to work correctly. But yes, this is what I was looking for, I don't know why I didn't think of it already.

Comment: @Malfist: Sorry, the previous syntax was for SQL Server. Shows you how long it is since I've done any SQL on either platform...

Comment: I noticed, I'm used to do SQL Server also, doing all this Oracle stuff has thrown me for a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle doesn't have an `ISNULL` function.  So you'd need something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM tableA
 WHERE brn_brand_id = filter
    OR (    brn_brand_id IS NULL 
        AND filter IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be handy at times:

```
   SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM tableA
   WHERE
      NVL(brn_brand_id, CHR(0)) = NVL(filter, CHR(0))
```