# Is there better Oracle operator to do null-safe equality check?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986386/how-to-make-null-equal-null-in-oracle), the way to perform an equality check in Oracle, and I want null to be considered equal null is something like

```
SELECT  COUNT(1)
  FROM    TableA
WHERE 
  wrap_up_cd = val
  AND ((brn_brand_id = filter) OR (brn_brand_id IS NULL AND filter IS NULL))
```

This can really make my code dirty, especially if I have a lot of where like this and the where is applied to several column. Is there a better alternative for this?

Comment: Also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636886/sql-not-equals-null

Comment: Too bad Oracle doesn't support the standard `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` operator.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I'm not sure if this is *better*, but it might be slightly more concise to use [`LNNVL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions091.htm), a function (that you can only use in a `WHERE` clause) which returns `TRUE` if a given expression is `FALSE` or UNKNOWN (`NULL`).  For example...

```
WITH T AS
(
    SELECT    1 AS X,    1 AS Y FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT    1 AS X,    2 AS Y FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT    1 AS X, NULL AS Y FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL AS X,    1 AS Y FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    T
WHERE
    LNNVL(X <> Y);
```

...will return all but the row where X = 1 and Y = 2.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative you can use `NVL` function and designated literal which will be returned if a value is null:

```
-- both are not nulls
SQL> with t1(col1, col2) as(
  2    select 123, 123 from dual
  3  )
  4  select 1 res
  5    from t1
  6  where nvl(col1, -1) = nvl(col2, -1)
  7  ;

       RES
----------
         1

-- one of the values is null
SQL> with t1(col1, col2) as(
  2    select null, 123 from dual
  3  )
  4  select 1 res
  5    from t1
  6  where nvl(col1, -1) = nvl(col2, -1)
  7  ;

  no rows selected

 -- both values are nulls
 SQL> with t1(col1, col2) as(
  2    select null, null from dual
  3  )
  4  select 1 res
  5    from t1
  6  where nvl(col1, -1) = nvl(col2, -1)
  7  ;

       RES
----------
         1
```

---

As @Codo has noted in the comment, of course,  above approach requires choosing a literal comparing columns will never have. If comparing columns are of number datatype(for example) and are able to accept any value, then choosing -1 of course won't be an option. To eliminate that restriction we can use `decode` function(for numeric or character datatypes) for that:

```
 with t1(col1, col2) as(
  2    select null, null from dual
  3  )
  4  select 1 res
  5    from t1
  6  where decode(col1, col2, 'same', 'different') = 'same'
  7  ;

       RES
----------
         1
```

Comment: This pattern only works if you can find a value that is not used in the source data (-1 in this example). If -1 is part of the source data, the comparison can return the wrong result.

Answer (score 3):

With the `LNNVL` function, you still have a problem when `col1` and `col2` (`x` and `y` in the answer) are both null. With `nvl` it works but it is inefficient (not understood by the optimizer) and you have to find a value that cannot appear in the data (and the optimizer should know it cannot).
For strings you can choose a value that have more characters than the maximum of the columns but it is dirty.

The true efficient way to do it is to use the (undocumented) function `SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL()`.

like this:

```
where SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL(col1) <> SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL(col2)
```

`SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL(a)` is equivalent to `nvl(a,'some internal value that cannot appear in the data but that is not null')`

Comment: Thanks for prettying my post!