# Simplest SQL expression to check if two columns have same value accounting for NULL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, null

I am trying to figure out the simplest *generalized* SQL expression that can check if two columns `a` and `b` are the same. In other words, an expression that evaluates to `true` when:

1. `a` is `NULL` and `b` is `NULL`; or
2. `a` is not `NULL` and `b` is not `NULL` and `a = b`

Assume columns `a` and `b` have exactly the same data type.

The most obvious solution, which I'm using in the below example, is horribly convoluted, particularly because I need to repeat this clause 15x in a 15-column table:

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT 'x' a, 'x' b FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'x' a, NULL b FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL a, 'x' b FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL a, NULL b FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'x' a, 'y' b FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT 'x' a, NULL b FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL a, 'y' b FROM dual
        UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL a, NULL b FROM dual

)

WHERE (a IS NULL AND b IS NULL) OR
      (a IS NOT NULL AND b IS NOT NULL AND a = b)
/
```

And the expected result is:

```
+--------+--------+
|   a    |   b    |
+--------+--------+
| x      | x      |
| (null) | (null) |
| (null) | (null) |
+--------+--------+
```

**tl;dr - Can I simplify my `WHERE` clause, *ie* make it more compact, while keeping it logically correct?**

P.S.: I couldn't give a damn about any SQL purist insistence that "`NULL` is not a value". For my *practical* purposes, if `a` contains `NULL` and `b` does not, then `a` *differs* from `b`. It is not "unknown" whether they differ. So please, in advance, no arguments up that alley!

P.P.S.: My SQL flavour is Oracle 11g.

P.P.P.S.: Someone decided this question is a duplicate of "[Is there better Oracle operator to do null-safe equality check?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13411819/1911388)" but a cursory check in that question will show that the answers are less helpful than the ones posted on this thread and do not satisfy *my particular, and explicitly-stated criteria*. Just because they are similar doesn't make them duplicates. I've never understood why people on SO work so hard to force my problem X to be someone else's problem Y.

Comment: I usually use `ISNULL()` function in SQL Server, I think `NVL()` is equivalent in Oracle, maybe try to take a look at that function?

Comment: NVL() won't work.   LNNVL ought to work.

Comment: `LNNVL` in that duplicate question is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: You're right. I'm blind. :(. Thanks @Noel. I didn't realize `LNNVL` is superior to `DECODE` but it is. I just voted close on my own question :)

Answer (score 2):

You can readily simplify it as:

```
WHERE (a IS NULL AND b IS NULL) OR
      (a = b)
```

The `IS NOT NULL` is not needed.

If you have a "safe" value (i.e. one that is never used), you can do this:

```
WHERE COALESCE(a, ' ') = COALESCE(b, ' ')
```

This assumes that `' '` is not a valid value.

Comment: The first one is definitely better. I did not realize that [the truth table for TRUE OR UNKNOWN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions004.htm#sthref2753) produced TRUE. I don't, however, have a safe value to use with `COALESCE`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the Ask Tom article ["Safely Comparing NULL Columns As Equal"](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4410543900346652511) to be the most helpful. In Oracle, you can use the [`DECODE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) function to do this:

```
 WHERE 1 = DECODE(a, b, 1, 0)
```

And this is the most compact solution I have seen so far.

Answer (score 0):

Simple is not necessarily performant.

consider this possibility.

```
WHERE X || 'x' = Y || 'x'
```

If you want to really push the envelope, use the **SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL**

Comment: I am not concerned with performant. I'm concerned only with compactness of the expression.

Comment: Interesting.  What is the business condition that is making that a concern?

Comment: Compactness and readability of code? A general bias toward being simple and terse instead of verbose and impossible to read. And I think you can safely assume since I stated compactness is the goal that I know enough about the data I am dealing with to know performance of the `WHERE` clause just isn't a big deal.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT 'x' a, 'x' b FROM dual
    UNION ALL
SELECT 'x' a, NULL b FROM dual
    UNION ALL
SELECT NULL a, 'x' b FROM dual
    UNION ALL
SELECT NULL a, NULL b FROM dual
    UNION ALL
SELECT 'x' a, 'y' b FROM dual
    UNION ALL
SELECT 'x' a, NULL b FROM dual
    UNION ALL
SELECT NULL a, 'y' b FROM dual
    UNION ALL
SELECT NULL a, NULL b FROM dual

)

WHERE NVL(a,'1')=NVL(b,'1')
```

Comment: Although '1' isn't in my example dataset, you can readily imagine that it might be in a real-world dataset. I would like a solution that doesn't require assuming that a given value won't appear in the dataset. See my comment to @Gordon Linoff's answer below: "I don't, however, have a safe value to use with COALESCE".

Comment: You could replace  '1' with something that will never appear in your dataset (it could be 'xxxxx' or 'aaaaa' or anything else)